# excel interop saveas not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, office-interop

I have the following code for creating and saving an excel file in c# but when it finishes, no file is created to my desktop, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

xlApp.Visible = false;

Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
Range rangeAToC = ws.get_Range("A1", "C1");

string[] headerRow = { "GIP Id", "First Name", "Last Name"};

int indexAtRow = 0;
foreach (Range cell in rangeAToC)
{
    cell.Value2 = headerRow[indexAtRow];
    indexAtRow++;
}

//Save report
wb.SaveAs("C:/Users/Abdul/Desktop/GipEmployeeReport.xls", Type.Missing,
 Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
 Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

//Close out COM objects
xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing i noticed is that your using forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes \

Comment: isn't that the alternative to escaping the backslashes?

Comment: son of a gun, that fixed it. In java you can use forward or back slashes, doesn't work with c#?

Comment: unfortunately not. you need to use \\ for a properly escaped \